# Communicate between a fragment and bottom sheet fragment via activity view model that could not work on set view visibility

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Forgive me if this sounds absurd. Here is the scenario, I have one activityViewModel that share communication between a screen fragment and a bottom sheet fragment. A bottom sheet fragment is used to select any payment card.Selecting a card from the bottom sheet leads to, selected card info will be displayed on the screen fragment: display card info(as text values) and status(as if the card is default card to pay that will set visible the default otherwise set gone)

My problem is, the display card info works(updating text values), but the status doesn't(set visibility)

I know this sounds like a matter of debugging, but really I striped down everything(including data binding), I couldn't find where the mistake is.

Here are codes snippet

**In activity**

```kotlin
private val viewModel by viewModels<PayingActivityViewModel>()
```

**In Screen Fragment**

```kotlin
private val activityViewModel by activityViewModels<PayingActivityViewModel>()

//...  

activityViewModel.cardStatusDisplay.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
      // THIS DOESN'T WORK
      if(it == true) scanPaying_tv_defaultStatus.visibility = View.VISIBLE
      else scanPaying_tv_defaultStatus.visibility = View.GONE
    })
```

**Bottom sheet fragment**

```kotlin
private val activityViewModel by activityViewModels<PayingActivityViewModel>()

...

selectExistingCards_btn_confirm.setOnClickListener {
      
      with(activityViewModel) {
        setSelectedPayingCard(selectedCard)
        setStatus(selectedCard?.cardData?.isDefault == true) // this is a code line that update live data in activity view model
        setSelectedCardPosition(selectedPosition)
      }

      dismiss()
    }
```

Thanks for helping.

---

**Update answer**

I found out the root cause for that horrible error, is that I'm using MotionLayout for the Screen Fragment layout, which prevent the visibility setting from working as expected. I'm working on the solution, however just wanted to update here, so you guys know why it is so weird. Thanks community.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `activityViewModel.cardStatusDisplay.observe` is called? If so, you can try `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`(and set `scanPaying_tv_defaultStatus` to invisible as well in your xml layout file)

If `activityViewModel.cardStatusDisplay.observe` is not called, then perhaps you forgot to trigger a refresh in `setStatus()`:

`activityViewModel.cardStatusDisplay.value = activityViewModel.cardStatusDisplay.value`

Comment: hi there, yes I'm pretty sure, debugged and everything.

Comment: hi @lerriuqs, I have updated the question for my investigation. Thanks for taking time

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is actually related to Motion Layout scene setup. Tldr reason is motion layout blocks control of visibility of all its children. MotionLayout is children of ConstraintLayout therefore it should be working the same thinking appears to be quite naive.

To resolve it, the visibility needs to be ignored as PropertySet, under the ConstraintSet start.

```xml
<Constraint
      android:id="@id/defaultStatus">
      <Layout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/card3"
        motion:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/cardNumber"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/paymentMethod"
        />
      <PropertySet
        android:visibility="visible"
        motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />
    </Constraint>
```

**Reference:** https://blog.stylingandroid.com/motionlayout-visibility/ *Thanks Mark for the awesome blog post.*